# How to display item value as a &Item. without refresh?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to display a value of an item like that:

```
Some text &P5_ITEM.
```

It's works only when I refresh a page, without refreshing I can only see a previous value of an item.

I tried to submit a item value with dummy pl/sql

```
null;

Items to Submit  &P5_ITEM.
```

but it didn't work

It's work only with a javacript

```js
 Location.reload()
```

But it is not a solution becouse it invokes reload after reload since dynamic action starts when page load.

Comment: what type of region is that text in ? Please provide as much info as possible that would allow others to help you. If I want to reproduce your problem - what steps should I perform ?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to fix that, instead of calculating value of an item in dynamic action fired when page load I passed value of the item in link attributies and it's working properly.

Comment: If you know what the value is when the page is rendered then a computation is also an option.